# Store UserID in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

When my app starts, the user is presented with a login screen.

When the form is submitted, if the credentials match, a UserID is returned.

How would I go about saving this so that I always have the userid on hand in queries etc?

And how would I access it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt provides a [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html) class that can be used to store the user's configuration data.

You can try something like this:

```
QSettings settings();
settings.setValue("userID", userID);                     // Save userID
QString userID = settings.getValue("userID").toString(); // Load userID
```

(The location of the saved settings will be based on the organization name and application name passed to [`QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#organizationName-prop) and [`QCoreApplication::setApplicationName()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop); if you don't call them, the settings will be stored in an undefined location).

Comment: Could you provide brief same code of how I would store a userid?

Comment: Using that, would I then be able to use an if statement on the userid to see if it's set? What is the function to check if something exists/ is set?

Comment: @Luke nandhp already included a link to the QSettings class documentation. The answers you seek are in the documentation.

Comment: If multiple instances of the app are run on one computer, I guess this solution doesn't allow each instance to have a different user logged on (this would be important in a factory environment where multiple users may share one log-in session). Is there a solution for that?